# Finding nCr value

Tags: c, combinations

I'm trying to find nCr value. There is no error but I'm getting 1 as the answer for all the inputs. Help me find the solution please.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fact(int num)
{
    int f=1,i;
    for(i=1;i<=num;i++)
    {
        f=f*1;
    }
    return f;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int n,r,ncr=0;
    printf("\n enter n and r values");
    scanf("%d%d",&n,&r);
    ncr=(fact(n) / (fact(r) * fact(n-r)));
    printf("\n ncr for %d and %d is %d",n,r,ncr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that a 32-bit `int` can only handle factorials up to `12!`, and a 64-bit `int` is only good up to `20!`

Answer (score 3):

It should not be f = f *1, but rather f = f * i

Answer (score 2):

Your factorial code is incorrect.

You set `f = 1`, then do `f = f * 1` a bunch of times. Then return `f` which is still `1`. I think you mean `f = f*i` right?

```
int fact(int num)
{
    int f=1,i;
    for(i=1;i<=num;i++)
    {
        f=f*i;
    }
    return f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method to compute factorial needs a correction. Should be :

```
int fact(int num)

{

    int f=1,i;
    for(i=1;i<=num;i++)
    {
        f=f*i;
    }
    return f;
}
```

Also, nCr is not defined if r > n. You should add this check after your scanf call.

Something like :
`if (r > n) printf("r cannot be greater than n.")`.

A more standard form of computing factorial is one that uses recursion.

```
int fact(int num)

{


  if (num == 1 || num == 0)

    return 1;

  else

    return (num * fact(num - 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better and faster approach would be to calculate nCr like this

```
int nCr(int n, int r) {
    if (r > n / 2) r = n - r;
    int ans = 1, i;
    for (i = 1; i <= r; i++) {
        ans *= n - r + i;
        ans /= i;
    }
    return ans;
}
```